# Javascript updates not posted, properties have default value on binding

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I'm struggling with this issue since yesterday. 
I have a simple ViewModel :

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    [Required]        
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
}
```

And this form :

```
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <section id="loginForm">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Latitude)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Longitude)
            }
```

And this javascript that is updating the textbox with user's location.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getPosition);
});

function getPosition(position) {
    document.getElementById("Latitude").value = position.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById("Longitude").value = position.coords.longitude;
}

<script>
```

And here is my action :

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

       return View()
   }
```

What really drives me crazy is that I can see that the textbox is properly filled with the coordinates in the browser, however nothing is received on the controller. All the properties : email, password, rememberbe etc... are correctly binded but these two. That's really weird.

Please I really need to solve that. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got it. It has nothing to do with javascript mechanisms, actually the problem was the delimiter for the number. By default javascript delimited the decimal part with a ".", I had to change it to a ",". I really hope it will save someone's else time.

I've never came accross this problem before, but I can't remember having posted double values in the past. We learn something new everyday.